# Excel table column formula does not return desired result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable

I have a "Report Deadline" column and  "Date Report Issued" column on my table, and both are date-only columns with rows that can be blank. My goal is to add an additional column to the table that says "TRUE" only if the Report Deadline date has already passed AND there is not a date in the Date Report Issued column, it should show "FALSE" for any other scenario.

The formula I have created is shown below

```
=AND([@[Report Deadline]]<TODAY(),[@[Date Report Issued]]="",[@[Report Deadline]]>0)
```

But this formula seems to just display FALSE for all of the values, how can I correct it.

Comment: Have you checked the results for the conditions individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (change the test for empty cell to isBlank()):

```
=AND([@[Report Deadline]]<TODAY(),ISBLANK([@[Date Report Issued]]),[@[Report Deadline]]>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.  =if(and(*[column 1 reference]*<Today(),not(isblank(*[column reference 2]*))),true